# WordPress Redirect from Post ID to another Post ID

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, post

I'm not sure how to right this, but I just want to redirect from one post ID to another.
(In my case, redirect from post id 1944 to 44). Thank you!

```
function redirectPost () {
global $post;
if ($post->ID == 1944) {
wp_redirect( get_page_link( 44 ), 301 );
exit;
}
```

Comment: You are missing a closing brace (}) for your function

Answer (score 0):

this can help:

```
add_filter('the_posts', function(){
    $newPostId = 12345;
    return [get_post($newPostId)];
});
```

Consider to do it in a plugin not in a theme.